# Django. How to create specific function in admin site that send a e-mail?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

How to create specific function in admin site that send a e-mail to People(email) with information (name, price) from my model ?

Something like this but "Sending email to selected people":

[image]

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class People(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
    email = models.EmailField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from demo.app.models import People

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email')

admin.site.register(People, PeopleAdmin)
```

email

```
send_mail('People information', 'People name is People.name, People price is People.price', 'mymail@gmail.com',
    ['email_from_email_field_from_model'])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need create a function, and make that.

```
def send_mail(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for msg in queryset:
        send_mail('People information', msg.name, msg.price, msg.email,
    [msg.email])
send_mail.short_description = u'Send e-mail to selected objs'

class PeopleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'email')
    actions = (send_mail,)
```

Comment: btw I would use a background task to send emails